# Conditional dependencies in `debian/control` file

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

I'm packaging the software, which depends on a particular version of a library shipped in the official Debian distribution. The software also has a bundled sources of the library.

Is there any way to describe this in the `debian/control` file that for Debian versions older than 10, I don't need to specify anything, but for >= 10, I can use the shipped version as a build requirement?

Also, for the older versions (how to detect it in the `debian/rules` file?) I have to pass an additional option to `cmake` at configure step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no provision for this: the expectation is that source packages (including `debian/control`) are uploaded to a specific distribution and release, with build instructions, including build dependencies, which work in that distribution.

In some circumstances it is possible to modify `debian/control` on the fly, from `debian/rules`, but that doesn’t work for build dependencies since they are resolved before the build starts.

In practice, there are two approaches which could work for you:

- use some sort of templating tool to take a common source and generate `debian/control` and `debian/rules` for each target you care about;
- use branches in a version control system to separate the various targets but still allow reasonably simple maintenance.

The latter is how most packages are maintained in Debian, when they need to allow uploads to multiple targets (*e.g.* experimental or stable or backports in addition to unstable).

> Also, for the older versions (how to detect it in the `debian/rules` file?) I have to pass an additional option to `cmake` at configure step.

You shouldn’t ever need to do this; instead of detecting the older version and hard-coding the behaviour, detect the behaviour you’re trying to implement. For example, check to see whether the dependency library is present on the system, and adjust the `cmake` invocation in consequence; or if it’s a `cmake` problem, detect the installed version of `cmake`.